# Does String.fromCharCode(decimal value) in javascript supports extended characters also

Tags: javascript, string

I am using function String.fromCharCode(decimal value), and passing a decimal value to it.

its working fine in terms of English characters, but when i m trying the same to decode for the Japanese characters, it gives me some arbit characters.

can anyone tell me does String.fromCharCode(decimal value) supports extended characters.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't support characters that use two surrogates.  [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/FromCharCode) has a utility function that is meant to handle this:

```
// String.fromCharCode() alone cannot get the character at such a high code point
// The following, on the other hand, can return a 4-byte character as well as the 
//   usual 2-byte ones (i.e., it can return a single character which actually has 
//   a string length of 2 instead of 1!)
alert(fixedFromCharCode(0x2F804)); // or 194564 in decimal

function fixedFromCharCode (codePt) {
    if (codePt > 0xFFFF) {
        codePt -= 0x10000;
        return String.fromCharCode(0xD800 + (codePt >> 10), 0xDC00 +
(codePt & 0x3FF));
    }
    else {
        return String.fromCharCode(codePt);
    }
}
```